# Adjacent vertices of a permutohedron which is the orbit of a point $x$ with repeated coordinates

Tags: convex-geometry, convex-polytopes, permutations, permutation-groups

**Question**: Let $x=(x_1, ..., x_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$, and let $P$ be the convex hull of the points formed by permuting the coordinates of $x$.  Given a vertex $y$ of $P$, what is a general rule for determining all vertices adjacent to $y$?

---

If all the coordinates of $x$ are distinct, $P$ is the usual permutohedron and vertices adjacent to $y$ are exactly those formed by transposing two consecutive coordinates of $y$.  My question is about the case where some coordinates of $x$ are the same.

Comment: Not arbitrary transposition, but only thiat which transposes two consecutive (with respect to the usual order) coordinates. The same if some coordinates are equal.

Comment: @FedorPetrov How is it the same if some coordinates are equal?  For example, if $x = (1,0,...,0)$, then $P$ is a simplex.  The adjacent vertices are *not* given by transpositions of consecutive coordinates.

Comment: Two coordinates $a<b$ are consecutive if there is no coordinate $c$ with $a<c<b$.

Comment: @FedorPetrov Ah, I see.  This answers my question.  Thank you!